# Yii2 db getStats (db queries number)

Tags: php, yii, yii2

There is useful method getStats in Db-component Yii

```
$sql_stats = YII::app()->db->getStats();
echo $sql_stats[0] //the number of SQL statements executed
echo $sql_stats[1] //total time spent
```

[Official documentation link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#getStats-detail)

Is there method in Yii2 to get this information?

Comment: So you want to get it to just see it or use in the code?

Comment: I want to get values in code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is equivalent for Yii 2:

```
$profiling = Yii::getLogger()->getDbProfiling();
```

`$profiling[0]` contains total count of DB queries, `$profiling[1]` - total execution time.

Note that if you want to get information about **all** queries at the end of request you should execute this code in right place, for example in `afterAction()`:

```
public function afterAction($action, $result)
{
    $result = parent::afterAction($action, $result);

    $profiling = Yii::getLogger()->getDbProfiling();

    ...

    return $result;
}
```

Otherwise you will get the information according to the moment of execution this command.

**Official documentation:**

- [getDbProfiling()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-log-logger.html#getDbProfiling%28%29-detail)
- [afterAction()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#afterAction%28%29-detail)

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the debugging toolbar you get a lot more info, it is much much better than this. Also you can enable logging that should also get you much more info.

More info on the debugging toolbar here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-debug-index.html and more info about the logging here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-logging.html